# Loop for each day in the current month and check rows for a match

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop

How can I write a loop to run for each day in the current month and then check to see if the Dataset has a record that matches one of those days and take an action?

```
For Day As Integer = 1 To DaysInTheMonth
        For Each row In MyRows
            If row.Date.Day = Day Then
                ' Yup! Found Data for this day!
                ' Add Data to string
            Else
                ' No Data To Display
                ' Add Blank Field String
            End If
        Next
Next
```

This generates too many rows in the table I have it building. Basically, every day gets as many rows as there are that contain data.

I'm building a HTML table that gets mapped into a chart using jquery so I need a  for everyday of the month.

Comment: Do you mean you are getting *blank fields* which you wanna ignore, maybe then you don't need the else part

Comment: If I dont have that else, it will not create the string to say nothing was done that date and it messes up the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what would more suit your run would be having a day counter in the loop for the rows, so that you don't actually run over all the days again for each record in the datatable.

So now if you have the record its added to the string else skipped and the dat is incremented, so going down further you should get the required datapoints. give it a try

```
For Each row In MyRows            
            If row.Date.Day = Day Then
                ' Yup! Found Data for this day!
                ' Add Data to string
            Else
                ' No Data To Display
                ' Add Blank Field String
            End If
            Day = Day + 1;
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You should drop the first For loop as that's causing all rows to be selected. Instead set Day = Today. Ie

Day as Integer =  date.day

Comment: If I drop the first loop then it will not run for everyday of the month, it will only run for days with data. I need it to run and graph even if there is no data.